# Who was able to teleport an item into the chest of his loan shark?

Tags: story-identification, tv, character-identification

I recall recently watching a show while half awake that was live action and one of the characters had the power to teleport to a location while holding a certain specific object, he could even teleport the object if it wasn't on his person, by simply saying the location aloud.  For example, he could say "home" and the object would return to him.

At one point, he teleported an item into the chest of his loan shark.

What could this character or story have been?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hutch from *[Jupiter's Legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter%27s_Legacy_(TV_series))*.

> Ian Quinlan as Hutch, George's son, who uses Blue Bolt's teleportation rod to commit crimes with his crew, attaining materials to make a portal to find his father.

In episode 3, "Painting the Clouds With Sunshine", Hutch uses the rod as you've described, [porting it into the mob bosses chest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BK7cmKrgsAo) using the destination 'Big Man's heart'.

> A gang of thieves indebted to the supervillain Big Man perform a series of heists. In a drunken stupor, Chloe accidentally stops one of their robberies and takes their loot. The thieves' leader, Hutch, kills Big Man to save himself and his friends, then uses Big Man's resources to retrieve what could be a powerful weapon.

Comment: Thanks! I obviously need to rewatch it!

Comment: A teleportation inspired, perhaps, by Larry Niven's short story "What Use is a Glass Dagger?"